# Get the value of a global variable related to a string

Tags: ruby

I need to convert a string `"variable_1"` into the value that the global variable `$variable_1` holds. The value of `$variable_1` will have already been defined. How can I convert a string into an object? Is this possible?

I looked at the method `instance_variable_set` but this does not suit my needs.

A thread on rubyforums advises that `eval` could be used, for example if I was to compare two variables using cucucmber and rspec, I could do something like:

```
Then(/^I expect my variables to be different "(.*?)" "(.*?)"$/) do |count1, count2|
  expect(eval("$#{count1}")).not_to eq(eval("$#{count2}"))
end
```

Is there another way to obtain a global variable from a string of its name?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. In one part of your question you are asking about variables, in another part of your question you are asking about objects, and in your title, you are asking about both interchangeably. Variables and objects are *completely different* things. Variables are *not* objects in Ruby. Strings are already objects, so there is no need to "convert them to objects".

Comment: Well, is it working?

Comment: @JörgWMittag apologies for confusion in original question, the eval way as described in my questions works fine, as for variables being objects...guess i took the "everything in ruby is an object" too literally, a variable is just a pointer to an object, something that can be accessed from memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` method like this

```
$variable_1 = "Try"
s = "variable_1"

eval("$#{s}")

puts $variable_1
# => Try
```